# Manipulate Active Document using openxml in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, openxml, office-interop, word-automation

I wrote a program using C# (Windows Form) that hosts MS Word inside a form (using Win Api) and the user can work with it. I don't want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to manipulate the active document.
Is there any way to manipulate the opened document using OpenXML?

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "winword.exe";
            
info.Arguments = "/q /w";
info.UseShellExecute = true;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = false;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
info.RedirectStandardError = false;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();

/// working with active document using openxml
```

Comment: Why do you need to host Word if you want to edit the document using the Open XML SDK?

Comment: OpenXML is designed to work with document files on disk, not documents opened in external processes such as Microsoft Word.